# Error while using Kendo Multi Select dropdrown in bootbox dialog in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, kendo-grid, bootbox

I am trying to use MultiSelect dropdown in bootbox dialog in MVC but it is not working for me.
I have tried putting the following code in bootbox.dialog in message

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("userRoles").DataTextField("RoleName").DataValueField("RoleID").Enable(true).BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName")))
```

I know for multiselect dropdown the following code will work but i need to use the kendo multiselect and i have noticed that outside the bootbox dialog it is working but errors out when used inside

```
@Html.ListBox("userRoles", new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It doesn't give any compile time error.
Error given below :

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at eval ()"

Comment: can you elaborate your question? in bootbox, you are not using kendo multiselect but HTML list box, so it will render a simple html listbox. Are you facing a compile time error or runtime error?

Comment: I have already created a bootbox dialog with some text box fields and dropdowns in it .so i need to add a new control ie the kendo dropdown control in the bootbox dialog.

Comment: check below the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand you need to render Kendo dropdown in the bootbox popup. You can do it as below:

Razor C#:

```
@{
    string htmlstring = "";
    htmlstring += "<select id='userRoles'>";
    foreach (Role role in ViewBag.Roles)
    {
        htmlstring += "<option value='" + role.RoleID + "'>" + role.RoleName + "</option>";
    }
    htmlstring += "</select>";
}
```

Script:

```
    <script>
        var renderString = "@Html.Raw(htmlstring)";
        var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
            title: 'A custom dialog with init',
            message: renderString
        });

        var required = $("#userRoles").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");

    </script>
```

Shown as:

[image]